# Copy all data from one database to the other MySQL - MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So I would like to make a test playground for my website where I don't alter with the original production data, and therefore I want to make a copy of all my data, and put it into another database. But how can I do this the right way?

I have a database with a lot of tables called **testreporting4**, and I want to make a copy of all the data/structure into the database called **testreportingdebug**

[From testreporting4 to testreportingdebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAtAj.png)

My database size is around 3.1GB at the moment (don't know if that changes anything)

Comment: *I want to make a copy of all my data, and put it into another database. But how can I do this the right way?* Backup current database and restore into another database will solve.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score -2):

I think the easiest way is the export the database and then import it. More information regarding exporting/importing MariaDB: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-and-export-databases-in-mysql-or-mariadb